# Catalina USB Drive

Tags: macos-catalina

Anyone know if you can install Apple 10.15 Catalina on a USB drive.  I see plenty of installers, however, I want to install it on a USB to test it out.  When I select my GUID USB drive I'm getting an ERROR_74CFD58E51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.. needed to partition as APFS.  Not installed on a bootable USB Drive.